# Pricing on google app engine for datastore read

Tags: google-app-engine

I am working on google app engine, i have a case of reading 5000 records from the datastore and this read operation can be called any number of times in a day. If i see the [**Pricing**](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/pricing) it says 50k operation are free per day after that it will be charged as $0.06 per 100,000 entities.

Here comes my question, since i am reading multiple number of times in a day surely it will be stored in shared cache. Whether reading from cache is counted as fetch operation in app engine ?

Comment: do not assume, look at the documentation for pricing, which does not mention caching. look at memcached to implement  caching.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Got complete idea now, i got this doubt because memcache is not working in my application.

Answer (score -2):

The link you mentioned is pricing for datastore. Cache is not datastore.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, cache is different but my assumption is when you read some data it will cached in app engine. If we send immediate next request for operation, it has to read from the cache (My assumption)

Comment: Because for each read oration i can see the increase in "Datastore Entity Fetch Ops" count

Comment: this is not an answer.